# Не знаю, захотел - поставил

Tags: грамотная-речь, тире, вопрос

Нужна ли запятая между "захотел" и "поставил

Comment: Думаю, нужно оставить тире.  Запятая здесь не совсем уместна, хотя можно между глаголами И поставить: захотел И поставил. И всё же отношения между частями предложения очень похожи на отношения между предложениями в БСП (быстрая смена событий, результат). Поэтому тире.

Answer (score 2):

***Не знаю, захотел — поставил.***

Здесь бессоюзная связь, тире обозначает причинно-следственные отношения (поставил, потому что так захотел).